# Single SQL query run against multiple linked SQL servers/DBs

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, sql-server-2008

I have a single SQL query that I need to run against ~25 different databases- each residing on a separate SQL server on the network. The query will run from a single central SQL server management studio, and the 24 other SQL server instances are linked. I have the query I need, and I tested that it works- however the goal is to create a script that queries each of the 25 separate SQL instances.

Instead of writing the query out 25 separate times within the script, I'm wondering if there's a way to utilize the single block of code to query each of the linked instances using an array, variables, DO/WHILE, a function or any other method.

Here's the query:

```
SET NOCOUNT ON

PRINT 'local server';
SELECT isc.ini_schema_name[Device], count(*) [Count]
FROM pharos.dbo.edi_pharos_stations eps, pharos.dbo.ini_schemas isc
WHERE eps.ini_schema_id = isc.ini_schema_id
GROUP BY isc.ini_schema_id, isc.ini_schema_name
```

For the purpose of this example, if I were to utilize the less-graceful approach of writing out the block of code 24 more times, this would be the next query in the script (to query SQL server hostnamed pharos90-2008).

```
PRINT 'Pharos90-2008';
SELECT isc.ini_schema_name[Device], count(*) [Count]
FROM [pharos90-2008].pharos.dbo.edi_pharos_stations eps, [pharos90-2008].pharos.dbo.ini_schemas isc
WHERE eps.ini_schema_id = isc.ini_schema_id
GROUP BY isc.ini_schema_id, isc.ini_schema_name
```

As you can see, the query / code is exactly the same except for the fact that it is referencing a separate linked SQL Server (query being run from a central SQL Server Management Studio).

The ultimate goal is to output the queried data for each SQL instance to a single .txt file; format being, print the name of each particular SQL server followed by the corresponding queried data.

Any advice as to how one would accomplish such a task?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It's one **query** (not a *querie*)  and two or more **queries**  ....

Comment: It's been a long day... do you have a useful suggestion for me?

Comment: Use SQLCMD mode and a variable for the server to connect to. Actually connect to each of the instances rather than using a linked server, run the query, then connect to the next one.

Answer (score 0):

Well, one way would be to create a cursor to iterate all of your linked servers.  (You can find linked servers like this...)

```
SELECT * FROM sys.servers WHERE is_linked = 1
```

Then, you could use the undocumented `sp_MSForEachDB` stored procedure to run a dynamic version of your query (changing the server on each iteration) on each database in the cursor's current server.  If you search for sp_MSForEachDB you can find plenty of information.  But [here's one link](http://weblogs.sqlteam.com/joew/archive/2008/08/27/60700.aspx) to save time.

Comment: thank you thank you, currently looking into how I could implement this method into my code.